# How to make a chatbot that only says one thing, while letting the user input as many inputs as they want using scanner

Tags: java

I was wondering how in Java, I could have the user input as many answers as they want, while the bot only replies with "Neat" or "...". I don't exactly have a good idea on how one would go to do this, and it would be nice if someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I have tried to set it up in a for loop type thing, but it kept crashing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will keep getting the next line in the while loop condition. If the length of the line is greater then 0, it will print neat. If the length is 0, meaning an empty line, then the condition will evaluate to false and the loop will exit.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String line;
System.out.println("Ask away. Empty line to stop.");
while ((line = scanner.nextLine()).length() > 0) {
    System.out.println("Neat");
}
```

In your while loop condition you can now also check for a specific stop command, e.g. typing "stop" will exit the loop:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String line;
System.out.println("Ask away. Type 'stop' to exit.");
while (!"stop".equals((line = scanner.nextLine()))) {
    System.out.println("Neat");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You were a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a while loop?

```
while (user response == true) {
ChatBot("Neat")
}
```

Something along those lines perhaps? Having a look at what you've already created would help.